# How to get compare-object output in file along with record count

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I am trying to append the output of compare-object of 2  rhash files to a file as well as count the records. The out-file was previously created in the script to capture a start time and eventually an end and elapsed time. This is my code for the compare and counter:

```
Compare-Object @objects | 
    % {$differences+=1} | 
        out-file -FilePath $resultsDir\CFRunResults-$runTimeStamp.txt -append
```

This produces the file but it is empty except for the start time written to it previously, and the $differences variable updates correctly but it doesn't appear in the file either. How would I go about getting the default compare-object output in a file as well as append to the output file the count of number of differences? Actually to be precise, in my application there will always be 2 differences I don't care about and since the remaining differences would be hash values for the same file list, differences on one side of the compare will have an equal number on the other. I plan to compute the value written to output file as $differences = ($differences - 2)/2.

Comment: How do you populate `@objects`?  What is `$differences`  I'd catch the output of `Compare-Object` in a variable - for example `$Comparison`. This way you could use `$Comparison.count` to get the count of the differences. ‍♂️

Comment: Your foreach-object is not outputting anything thus empty file

Comment: Sorry, I forgot @objects. $objects = @{
  ReferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path $tempDir\CompareTemp.txt)
  DifferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path $tempDir\PhysicalUSBHash.txt)}

Comment: I'm new to Powershell, how would I make the @foreach output something?

Comment: @Olaf, I'd mark your comment as answer if I knew how. Thanks, it's also simpler than what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Lando pipe the result to the Success stream.    

In this case two possibilities are  `% { return $differences+=1 } | Out-File ` or `% { $differences+=1 | Out-File -Append }` (replacing as needed, of course)

Comment: @Lando For future questions: if you forgot something you should go back, [edit] your question once again and add what you forgot. Do not add it as comments. It is not possible to mark a comment as solution. I wouldn't mind if you deleted your question now that you have a solution. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

- The **simplest and faster solution** is:

  ```bash
  @(Compare-Object @objects).Count > $resultsDir\CFRunResults-$runTimeStamp.txt
  ```

  - Use `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to capture the output from [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) and make sure it is treated as an array even if there happens to be just *one* output object.
  - Use `.Count` to get the array's element count (`.Length` would work too, but `.Count` is preferable as it works on other list-like types too).
  - [Redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `>` is in effect the same as [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) with its default behavior. Thus, if no opt-in behavior such as `-Encoding` is needed, it is a more concise alternative. Note that unless you meant to append to *preexisting content* in the output file, there's no need for `-Append` (whose equivalent redirection operator is `>>`).
- The ***immediate* problem with your code** was:

  - `$differences+=1` is an [*assignment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators) and assignments do *not* produce *pipeline output*, so that `Out-File` received *no input*.
  - However, by enclosing assignments in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), you can make assignments *pass the assigned value through*.

    - As an aside: the simpler equivalent of `$differences+=1` is `++$differences`, i.e. use of the prefix form of the [increment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators#the-increment-and-decrement-operators).
    - A simplified example:

      ```bash
      # -> !! NO OUTPUT
      $num = 0
      'a', 'b', 'c' | % { $num+=1 }

      # -> Outputs 1, 2, 3 - thanks to the (...) enclosure
      $num = 0
      'a', 'b', 'c' | % { ($num+=1) }
      ```